# Access 2003: Show hidden menus

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2003

I'm wanting to investigate a problem with a former colleague's Access 2003 database/application. When I fire up the database, a default form opens; when I press F11 to look at the underlying code, the expected dialog opens but I don't have access to all the menus and rt-click functionality is disabled.

There is an autoexec macro, which sets warnings on, runs 3 queries, and opens a form. The form load event doesn't reveal much either.

How can I open this DB such that I can edit it again, that is, so that I have full menus and right click functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, solution was found immediately after posting!

I tried pressing Shift whilst opening the database, which I was led to believe would prevent autoexec and other settings from kicking in, but it didn't work.

However, having tried again (after disabling the security warning that came up), the Shift trick did work.

Then I clicked on Tools > Startup, and ticked the following options:

- Allow Full Menus
- Allow Default Shortcut Menus

... and the next time I opened the DB, the menus were as expected.

Comment: honestly the shift key worked for me. thanks a ton